# Write for logical value Matlab

Tags: matlab

Let's say `T=1:20 ; P=[2 6 9 11 15 19]`.

How to write a logical value for `P` in range `T`?

The answer I want is: `flag= [0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0]`.

Comment: Is `T` always `1:n`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a logical vector `flag` the size of `T`, then use `P` as an index vector of the flag to raise to `true`:

```
T=1:20 ; P=[2 6 9 11 15 19] ;

flag = false(size(T)) ;
flag(P) = true ;

flag =
     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) made for exactly this task -

```
ismember(T,P)
```

Comment: Wow, how could I forget ismember?

Comment: This solution is probably actually safer since it's the only one that will not expand `T` if an element of `P` happens to be outside its range.

Answer (score 2):

For the fun of it, an alternative to Hoki's answer:

```
T(P) = 0;
flag = ~T
```

This sets all values that are in P equal to zero, and then checks if the values in T is 0 or not. This of course has the downside that it overwrites `T`. Note: I would go for Hoki's answer!